# Shortening strings in C

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to shorten a string length to be displayed (`printf`). For example I ask user to enter a name, then the program will only display back 15 characters of it.

This is snippet of my code:

```
int score1=0,score2=0,foul1=0,foul2=0,rebound1=0,rebound2=0,assist1=0,assist2=0,missed1=0,missed2=0,choice1,choice2,choice4,choice5=0;
char choice3,home[15]="HOME",away[15]="AWAY";

printf("\t\t\t==================================\n\t\t\t||     NETBALL SCOREKEEPER\t||\n\t\t\t==================================\n\n");

do
{
    printf("Do you want to enter teams' names?\n1-Yes\n2-No\n:>>");
    scanf("%d",&choice1);
    switch(choice1)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                do
                {
                printf("\nPlease enter HOME team's name(max 15 characters including space)\n:>>");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s",&home);
                printf("\nPlease enter AWAY team's name(max 15 characters including space)\n:>>");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s",&away);
                do
                {
                printf("\n\n%s VS %s\n\n1.Confirm\n2.Edit\n:>>",home,away);
                scanf("%d",&choice2);
                if(choice2!=1&&choice2!=2)
                    printf("\n***ERROR. INVALID INPUT***\n\n");
                }
                while (choice2!=1&&choice2!=2);
                }
                while(choice2==2);
                break;
            }
    case 2:
                {
                printf("\nSet up to default:\n%s VS %s\n\n",home,away);
                break;
                }
    default:
        {
        printf("\n***ERROR. INVALID SELECTION***\n\n");
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TLDR: `printf("%.15s\n", "0123456789fifteen");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code has input and output issues;

```
char home[15]="HOME";
...
printf("Do you want to enter teams' names?\n1-Yes\n2-No\n:>>");
scanf("%d",&choice1);
...
printf("\nPlease enter HOME team's name(max 15 characters including space)\n:>>");
scanf(" %[^\n]s",&home);
...
```

Input1: The `'s'` in `" %[^\n]s"` is certainly not needed.  `'s'` is not part of the `"%[^\n]"` format specifier.

Input2: If "max 15 characters", then `home[15]` is too small to save 15 `char` plus the terminating null character `'\0'`.  Should be `home[15+1]`.

Input3: Code does not limit user input to 15, it only request user to limit input.  Users are evil - do not trust them to limit input as requested.  Using `"%15[^\n]");` limits the number of save `char` to 15.

Input4: Far better to use `fgets()` for user input.   Read user input into a reasonable size buffer and *then* scan it.

Input5: Coding both `scanf()` with `fgets()` is a problem.  `scanf("%d",&choice1);` typically leaves a `'\n'` in `stdin`, that `fgets()` will consume only that.

[Edit] Input6: ([@Cool Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049655/cool-guy)) `&home` should be `home`.

Input solution #1: quick, but not robust:

```
char home[15+1]="HOME";
...
printf("\nPlease enter HOME team's name(max 15 characters including space)\n:>>");
scanf(" %15[^\n]", home);
...
```

Input solution #2: more robust:

```
char home[15+1]="HOME";
char buf[50];
...
printf("Do you want to enter teams' names?\n1-Yes\n2-No\n:>>");
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, "%d",&choice1) != 1 || choice2 < 1 || choice2 > 2) {
  printf("\n***ERROR. INVALID INPUT***\n\n");
  break;
}
...
printf("\nPlease enter HOME team's name(max 15 characters including space)\n:>>");
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
if (sscanf(buf, " %15[^\n]", home) != 1) {
  Handle_BadNameInput();  // all spaces
}
...
```

Output:
To print a string with a maximum number of `char` uses `"%.*s"`

```
printf("%.*s", max_Length, str);
```

---

More checks could be added:
1. Insure user input does not have *additional* data on the line.
2. Check for EOF.

Comment: if i use solution 1.. & i enter >15 characters, the remaining characters after 15th one will straightly go to AWAY.. how to fix this? btw thanks, your explanation really lighten up my prob :)

Comment: @programmer dreamer 1) recommend 2nd solution.  2) Your comment stated the problem "enter >15 characters ... will straightly go to AWAY", but did not state the desired goal.  When the problem happens (user enters too much data) what should happen? truncation?, exit code? have _no_ input limit?  Each of these approaches entail more code.  As mentioned, user input can be hostile. Best to separate user input from scanning: Get the input, then scan it.

Comment: and if i use solution 2, it will skip to confirmation part & ask user to enter back the teams' names.. (if more than 15 characters)

Comment: @programmer dreamer Your comment is unclear to me: "skip to confirmation part & ask user to enter back the teams' names".  Is this what your think the code does (which reads up to 49 char) or what you want the code to do?

Comment: [here is the screenshot of what i mean] (http://s10.postimg.org/8cgmp6do9/prob_prog.png)

Comment: Isn't `&home` in the second and third arguments of `scanf` and `sscanf` respectively be simply  `home`?

Comment: @programmer dreamer To check if user input (ignoring leading spaces), is too long also, code could use `int n; if (sscanf(buf, " %15[^\n] %n", &home, &n) != 1 || buf[n]) {   Handle_BadNameInput();  }`.  `"%n"` saves the index where coding stopped.  If, after white-space, scanning did not stop on a `'\0'`, then something extra occurred and is a user input error.

Comment: @Cool Guy You are correct - keen eye.  Post updated.   `&home` --> `home`.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your question `Shortening strings in C`

You can do it by

```c
char str[20];
fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); /* scanf is nasty for reading strings, use fgets instead (see buffer overflow) */
printf("%.ns",str); /* n = number of characters to be printed out */
```

prints out n characters in the string left aligned.

If string is `str = "someString"` and you need to print out just 4 characters in it you can do

```c
printf("%10.4s",str);
```

Where 10 specifies the field length and 4 specifies the number of characters to be printed out.

Comment: More precisely by `printf("%.ns",str);`

Comment: Or `str[n] = 0` and then simply `printf("%s",str)`.

Comment: What does the dot do?

Comment: @CoolGuy I have explained in detail

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for reading strings from the user, use `fgets` instead!

Comment: @d3l Yes that is better to avoid buffer overflow but not required we take care of it else then why does the standard have scanf() still

Comment: @Gopi Because of historical reasons. And in your example, you didn't take care of it.

Comment: @d3l It looks like you are totally against `scanf()` .. Since there are concerns while using scanf() and fgets() is safer way I will agree with your edits :)

Comment: @Gopi I'm not totally against it. But its very dangerous to read strings with scanf.

Comment: @d3l Yes SIR... I am with you thats why I approved your changes

Comment: @Gopi Yeah... whatever.